# Read string constant to non constant variable in C

Tags: c, string, constants

```
const char* string_b10_e2 = {"base 10"}; //base 10
```

Is there a way to read the value "base 10" in a non constant string variable?
I know I CANNOT use a char*, like shown below

```
char * str,
str =  string_b10_e2; //not allowed
```

as it breaks the promise of keeping the string constant.
But is there a way to read the value into a non-constant string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can copy the string. [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)

Comment: `const char* string_b10_e2 = {"base 10"};` is not good

Comment: `char * tempString = (char*) malloc(strlen(string_b10_e2));
strcpy(tempString,string_b10_e2);`
Can't you use this?

Comment: C does not have a string type. `string_b10_e2` is not a string, but a pointer! What do you want to achieve? If you cannot answer that in an understandable way, please read a C book (pointers and array section and `string.h`)

Comment: @Boiethios Op's initialization is correct. Please read this: https://ideone.com/dGqc7i

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for getting that to my notice, sorry about that. Yes I am aware C does not have string type and char* is the way to get string-like variables in C. I am modifying a code where I need to read values from constant pointers into another variable .

Comment: @user3443084: No, it is not! A pointer is not an array s not a pointer. And a "constant pointer" (`char * const cp`) is something very different from what you ask for. Also note that C also does not have symbolic constants other than _enum-constants_.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks! I do need to read the book for clarity. I guess I was trying to say how to get the string literal into another variable. Thanks!

Comment: @user3443084: There are already many questions about _how to copy a string in C_. Why did none of them help?

Comment: @2501 thanks for the link.

Comment: @Olaf it is the usage of char* const that I am finding trouble with. Not just copy between two strings. Thanks!

Comment: @user3443084: You confuse "pointer to `const char`" and "`const` pointer to `char`". Your question is about the first.

Comment: I am sorry ..yes your are right about that but my point is I am new to this concept and  I did research the site for related questions and none of them answered my question. Hence I posted a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to read the value "base 10" in a non constant string
>   variable?

You can use an `union`

```
union fake {
    const char *as_const;
    char *as_non_const;
};

union fake x;
x.as_const = string_b10_e2;
```

and then use `x.as_non_const`, but keep in mind that you can not modify his contents (it is still in a read only data segment)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a string to a `char *` pointer after initialization using the conventional assignment operator.

You can, however, use the `strcpy` function. If you declare it as just a pointer instead of an array with fixed length, you also need to allocate memory for the string:

```
char *str = NULL;
str = malloc(20);
if(str == NULL) return;
strcpy(str, "Hello World!\n")
printf("%s", str);
free(str);
str = NULL;
```

Comment: Don't cast `void *` to pointers in C. And your code is a massive security risk if the original string is a variable/parameter.

Comment: @Olaf security risk? Please explain

Comment: What happens if the original string has a length >19?

Comment: @Olaf in this case we're copying a string literal which we know for certain to have a length less than 19, not a variable, so we know that we won't hit that case.

Comment: Please read my first comment carefully. Especially the last part ... Alternatively, what happens if you edit the literal lateron? Redundancy is a root of all evil in C.

Comment: This code is also a huge security risk if it happened to use `gets`. Luckily it doesn't, so it isn't. Strawman argument is not an argument.